# 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver' while trying to generate a model class

Tags: php, mysql, yii

When I run in yiic shell a command

> model Users ygs_users

I get following error

> exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open
>   the DB connection: could not find driver' in
>   C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\yii-1.1.16.bca
>   042\framework\db\CDbConnection.php:399

Earlier I had such warnings as I was entering in the yiic shell

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/php5/ext\p hp_gd2.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.  in
>   Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library '/usr/local/php5/ext\p hp_mbstring.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ
>   ьюфєы№.  in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\p hp_mysql.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ
>   єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.  in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\p hp_mysqli.dll' -
>   ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.  in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP
>   Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\p
>   hp_pdo_mysql.dll' - ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.  in Unknown on line 0

I have appointed an absolute path to the extensions in php.ini and the warnings are gone. Also I have inserted a line 'PDO support = enabled' in php.ini.
But error 'CDbException' remains the same.

My database.php

> return array(     //'connectionString' =>
>   'sqlite:'.dirname(**FILE**).'/../data/testdrive.db',  // uncomment the
>   following lines to use a MySQL database       'connectionString' =>
>   'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',  'emulatePrepare' => true,
>     'username' => 'root',   'password' => '',   'charset' => 'utf8',     );

I'm using yii-1.1.16.

Comment: first run  phpinfo();  to see PDO driver is enable for mysql ? after setting 'PDO support = enabled' in php.ini.  restart your server

Comment: It turns out that the problem is already solved. I restarted the server after setting 'PDO support = enabled' but changes not take effect immediately. Now all works.

Answer (score 0):

After using Yii for 4 1/2 years I got caught me out for 10 mins... I accidentally included a "£" (UKP symbol) in the mysql password so everything worked from "mysql -u blah -p db" but Yii wouldn't connect.

If you are scratching your head over this error check your p/w doesn't have anything silly in it.